# Designing a service/business logic layer that returns useful/consistent messages

Tags: c#

This is a question regarding design of a service or business logic layer that returns or exposes messages meaningful to the user.

`RegisterUser` method that takes a user.  What should it return? Should it always return

- a Service Information object?
- a newly created user?
- a boolean, and based on the result, you can interrogate this service's error messages?

```
public bool RegisterUser(User user)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.EmailAddress) || !user.EmailAddress.IsValidEmailAddress())
    {
        AddMessage(new Message
        {
            Description = "Invalid Email Address",
            Success = false
        });
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password))
    {
        AddMessage(new Message
        {
            Description = "Password is Required",
            Success = false
        });
    }
    return Messages.Count == 0;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about design and not a code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with returning a message like this is that you are "hard coding" the messages in the registration method.  If you want to add localization (i.e. return a message in the users language as determined by the culture setting of the client) to the application later it will be much harder.  A cleaner approach would be to use custom exceptions and exception handling.  For example, if the an invalid email address is entered then a `InvalidEmailException` would be thrown by the `RegisterUser` method.  The part of the application that calls the `RegisterUser` method would determine what to present to the user for this type of exception or to percolate it up higher in the application for handling.  This is a cleaner separation of concerns of handling exceptions in the application from what is presented to the user.  This also promotes reuse because different users of the method may want to handle it differently.

Comment: although I am happy with your solution, I personally think that throwing exceptions is bad practise and exceptions should only be thrown in exceptional cases. It's not exceptional that a user might enter an incorrect email address.

Comment: I however concur with your localization issue. Thank you for that

Comment: I guess we agree to disagree then.  Google InvalidPasswordException and see how many libraries use exception handling for authentication processing.  Using exceptions for these scenarios is not a bad practice at all for the reasons I spell out in my answer.

Comment: Kevin, thanks once again for the answer, much appreciated, it seems to be the most common solution to this kind of problem